# Roslyn TypeDeclarationSyntax, MethodDeclarationSyntax, FieldDeclarationSyntax have common properties but no common base class or interface

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

**What I am trying to do:**

I am writing a code refactoring using roslyn. My goal is to carve out a calss. So what I am doing is basically I am deleting all private staff and replacing bodies of non private staff with a `throw new NotImplementedException()`.

**What is my problem:**

Everything works fine, but I ended up with a lot of code duplication like this:

```
    private static bool IsPrivate(TypeDeclarationSyntax type)
    {
        return type.Modifiers.Any(IsPrivateModifier);
    }

    private static bool IsPrivate(MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
    {
        return method.Modifiers.Any(IsPrivateModifier);
    }

    private static bool IsPrivate(FieldDeclarationSyntax field)
    {
        return field.Modifiers.Any(IsPrivateModifier);
    }

    private static bool IsPrivate(PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
    {
        return property.Modifiers.Any(IsPrivateModifier);
    }

    private static bool IsPrivate(IndexerDeclarationSyntax property)
    {
        return property.Modifiers.Any(IsPrivateModifier);
    }

    private static bool IsPrivateModifier(SyntaxToken modifier)
    {
        return modifier.Kind() == SyntaxKind.PrivateKeyword;
    }
```

The reason is that I need to use a property `Members` and there is no common base type or interface for syntax classes which will declare `Members`. I have the same problem with property `Body` which is common to all these, bu there is no common base or common interface.

**Questions:**
Is there any reason why API design is like this, or am I missing something? is there any pattern how I can avoid duplication in these and many other similar cases.

---

**Update**
Created an issue in the roslyn repo: [#10455](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10455)

Comment: I suggest that you request this at [the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues). There is already [a similar issue for `Identifier`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9908).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope they fix that but you can

```
dynamic
```

around it for now.